# Having a function return a mutable AnyObject

Tags: swift

I have a function that scans subviews for a certain ID, and when it finds it it returns an AnyObject

```
func whatever(ID: String) -> AnyObject? { }
```

My problem is I can't do anything with the object returned because it's read-only (immutable). I tried not returning an optional, but I get the same problem. All I try to do is change it's alpha property but I'm now allowed.

If classes in swift are reference types, it should let me do whatever I want with the returned object since it's a pointer.

Any ideas?

Comment: try using `var` instead of `let`

Comment: Do you unwrap the object before trying to access its properties and methods? Also do you cast the object to the actual type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fixed it by returning a UIView instead of AnyObject, since I positively know all those objects will be subclasses of UIView. I could then mutate their alpha property.